# Why does the "catch" in try catch declare type of $e

Tags: php, try-catch

```
try {

} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

I thought PHP had type inference. Why is it neccesary to declare the type of the variable --$e-- ?

Comment: Because there can be multiple exception types, and you might want to do different things based on which instance of exception it was, seeing you can  stack `catch` keywords.

Comment: [What is $e in catch($e) while error or exception handling in PHP?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-e-in-catch-e-while-error-or-exception-handling-in-PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can throw different classes of exceptions. You can use that to your advantage to add proper code for error handling.

A `try` block can be followed by any number of `catch` blocks.

Example:

```
try 
{
}
catch(\PDOException $e)
{
    // Something bad happened while dealing with database
}
catch(\LengthException $e)
{
    // Length exception occurred
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    // The \Exception is the parent class for all exceptions, this handles anything not caught in above example
}
```

Using the above sample, you can take proper measures for handling errors depending on *why* they occurred. That means you can throw exceptions that you defined. It's the best if you don't overdo it and swap out entire error handling with exceptions. Exceptions occur when something abnormal in the code flow occurs, for example - a connection to MySQL broke mid-transaction.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Can this type forcing behavior work for functions as well?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If a function throws an exception then yes.. anything can throw an exception or any type of exception.

Comment: for example could I declare a function like --- function acceptException(Exception $e){  }

Comment: So you want to use a function to handle exceptions when they occur? You can do that. Refer to [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) which helps you implement such behaviour. You can specify functions that deal with specific exceptions once they occur.